# Show YouTube video in Twig from the URL

Tags: html, youtube

I'm trying to show Youtube videos in Symfony (in the Twig template). I can't use the  iframe method because I need to use the general URL (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUjeps1hxIw&t=671s instead of https://www.youtube.com/embed/jUjeps1hxIw).

I have found examples with the HTML tag  but they doesn't work.

Comment: how about you use embed youtube?

Comment: It doesn't help me because it doesn't work whit the type of URL I use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution. I had to change the url, what is that I didn't want.

```
<div id="youtube-ficha">
            {% for artistYoutube in group.youtube %}

            <iframe class="myIframe" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>


            <script type="text/javascript">

                var url = "{{ artistYoutube}}";
                var id = url.split("?v=")[1]; //sGbxmsDFVnE

                var embedlink = "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + id;

                var ytube1 = document.getElementsByClassName("myIframe");

                ytube1[{{loop.index0}}].src = embedlink;
            </script>

            {% endfor %}    
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use  tag you can use

```
<object width="420" height="315"
data="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jUjeps1hxIw">
</object>

<embed width="420" height="315"
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jUjeps1hxIw">
```

but you have to give the embed link of your you tube video which you can find by following below steps

1. play your video on you tube
2. right click on your video
3. select copy embed code
4. past it in notepad and copy that link and use it in above tag